# How to Testing with proxy servers

Tags: .net-2.0, proxy

I have some code in .NET V2.0 that is talking to an asmx service 
As a related issue I also have some code in the same winforms app that is doig BITS uploads
We are a very small shop and quite frankly do not have any sort of proxy server setup
But of course our clients will
I want to test with  a proxy server sitting between my home FIOS connection and the internets and I want to test when auth information is required against the proxy server
Clearly the number of configurations in the wild are way many but any suggestions welcome
1) Any public proxy servers where I can create credential based accounts and test?
2) any catch all .NET solution like asking for creds setting them somehow on BITS uploads and asmx services  and then just assuming they work 90% of the time

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could run a proxy server on your own computer, then 'connect to yourself' as the proxy.